# Finding file size windows MFC application

Tags: windows, mfc, filesize

I am working on a Windows MFC application. I am preparing a report list in my design
using `CListCtrl` were I can list the name, size, type and modified date of the file. I do not know how to display the size of a file. Do any one know how to do that?

Comment: see similar question with answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238603/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get all your info in one shot, use:

```
CFileStatus filestatus;
CFile::GetStatus( filename, filestatus );
```