# Get File size from CFileDialog

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cfiledialog

I am newbie from Visual Studio C++. I am using CFileDialog to get the file name and file path from user input. and now i want to use progress control that is loading process and user have to wait depend on your input file size. Now I got the file name and file path by using CFileDialog but I don't know how to get a user input file size.

I am using below method and it always return zero.

```
int FileSize(const char * szFileName)
{
struct stat fileStat;
int err = stat(szFileName, &fileStat);
if (0 != err) 
    return 0;
return fileStat.st_size;
}
```

Please suggest me if you have a better solution to get a file size.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b569d0t4.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard portable way to do it would be:

```
long long sz;   // int would be to small for many files ! 
ifstream ifs(test);
if(!ifs) 
    return 0;   // when file couldn't be opened
ifs.seekg(0, ios::end);   
sz = ifs.tellg();
return sz;
```

The native windows approach would be to use [`GetFileSize()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But if you look at an MFC alternative that doesn't open the file first, you may look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1801959/3723423).