# Trying to read a file into a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I am trying to read all the characters in a file into an array.  Assuming all variables are declared, why are all the characters not being read into my array.  When I output some of the characters in the "storeCharacters[]" array, garbage is being returned.  Please help.

This is my function:

```
void countChars(ifstream& input, char storeCharacters[])
{
int i = 0;
    while( !input.eof() )
    {
        input.get(storeCharacters[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you allocate space for the characeters?

Comment: You could eliminate the function by using the `input.read` method.

Comment: try using while( input.good() && !input.eof() ) as eof is not only the attribute saying stream is unreadable. However, "Assuming all variables are declared ..." :-)

Answer (score 2):

After the while loop try adding `storeCharacters[i] = '\0'` to null terminate the string.

Comment: I am not sure if that did anything... I do not know how to allocate space for characters.

Answer (score 0):

The easy fix to your problem if you know the maximum size of your file, then just set your array to have that size and initialize it with `\0`.

let's say the maximum characters count in your file is `10000`.

```
#define DEFAULT_SIZE 10000
char  storeCharacters[DEFAULT_SIZE];
memset (storeCharacters,'\0',DEFAULT_SIZE) ;
```

The below post should be the correct way to read a file using a buffer it has memory allocation and all what you need to know :

[Correct way to read a text file into a buffer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029103/correct-way-to-read-a-text-file-into-a-buffer-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;


void getFileName(ifstream& input, ofstream& output)  //gets filename
{
string fileName;

cout << "Enter the file name: ";
cin >> fileName;
input.open(fileName.c_str());   
if( !input )
    {
        cout << "Incorrect File Path" << endl;
        exit (0);
    }
output.open("c:\\users\\jacob\\desktop\\thomannProj3Results.txt");
}

void countWords(ifstream& input)  //counts words
{
bool notTrue = false;
string words;
int i = 0;

while( notTrue == false )
{
    if( input >> words )
    {
        i++;
    }
    else if( !(input >> words) )
        notTrue = true;
}
cout << "There are " << i << " words in the file." << endl;
}

void countChars(ifstream& input, char storeCharacters[], ofstream& output)  // counts characters
{
int i = 0;

        while( input.good() && !input.eof() )
        {
                input.get(storeCharacters[i]);
                i++;
        }
        output << storeCharacters[0];
}

void sortChars()  //sorts characters
{
}

void printCount()  //prints characters
{
}

int main()
{

ifstream input;
ofstream output;

char storeCharacters[1000] = {0};

getFileName(input, output);
countWords(input);
countChars(input, storeCharacters, output);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: im sure its something simple.... why can't I store characters from the file into the storeCharacters[] array under the countChars function?