# Write into text file line by line c

Tags: c, file, text, kernel, line

I've written a user space program to read from a kernel device line by line, somehow, the data is always overriden with each read. Can you please tell me how to fix my code?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
 

#define BUFFER_LENGTH 256

int main()

{

  int  ret,fd;
  char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
  FILE * fPtr;
  unsigned int i=0;

  if((fd = open("/dev/show_log_device_dev", O_RDWR)) == -1){
    perror("Failed to open the file");
  }
  //printf("/dev/show_log_device_dev opened.\n");
  //fflush(stdout);

  fPtr = fopen("log.txt", "w+");

  int bytesRead = 0;

  while (bytesRead < sizeof(buffer)) {
    int ret = read(fd, buffer + bytesRead, sizeof(buffer) - bytesRead);
    if (ret == 0)
        break;
    if (ret == -1) {  
      perror("Failed to read the message from the device.");
      return errno;
      /* Handle error */
    }
    bytesRead += ret; 
    printf("read from /dev/show_log_device_dev. %s\n",buffer);

  }
  if(lseek(fPtr,0,SEEK_SET)!=0) {
    fprintf(fPtr,"%s",buffer);
  }

  fclose(fPtr);
}
```

I would like the output file "log.txt" to contain all the lines written to buffer with each read line after line sith skip-line between lines. Please show me the proper way to do it inctead of the fprintf attempt I've written above.

Thank you.

Comment: Why the `lseek()`? And are you ever making sure `buffer` is a proper 0 terminated string?

Comment: I didn't verfiy that buffer is 0 terminated... Also, I used lseek to find the end of the file and write to it, at least that's what I though this from of writing does. I need the proper way to write into that file line by line, i.e. write `buffer` into the file at the first available spot in the following line. I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Try following the solution here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029103/correct-way-to-read-a-text-file-into-a-buffer-in-c>.

Comment: You're seeking to the *beginning* of the file... (Also `lseek()` is for file descriptors, not `FILE` pointers. How does that compile?)

Comment: @Mensch677 The sulotion doesn't help becuase the situation is too different, I'm not trying to read from a file, but from a device. I want to write to a file, and make it line by line.

Comment: @Shawn Then what is the proper way to write the lines so they would appear one after the other in log.txt? (Assume the line is written correctly into `buffer`)

Comment: User-space code looks reasonable. except `lseek` call for `FILE*`. "the situation is too different, I'm not trying to read from a file, but from a device." - Reading from the device shouldn't differ from reading from a text file... unless your device is very special. In the last case you need to provide the code for your device, otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: when compling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for gcc, at a minimum use: `gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: regarding: `if(lseek(fPtr,0,SEEK_SET)!=0) {` This places the file pointer at the beginning of the file,  Not what you want to do.  also, `lseek()` returns a `off_t` not a `int`

Comment: regarding: `printf("read from /dev/show_log_device_dev. %s\n",buffer);`    need to NUL terminate the 'buffer[]' data before trying to print it.  Suggest inserting, just before the above line, `buffer[ bytesread ] = '\0';`

Comment: regarding: `int ret = read(fd, buffer + bytesRead, sizeof(buffer) - bytesRead);`  The function: `read()` returns a `ssize_t`, not a `int`

Comment: at some point, the value calculated by `read(fd, buffer + bytesRead, sizeof(buffer) - bytesRead);` will exceed the length of the buffer and/or the calculation: `sizeof(buffer) - bytesRead`  will return a negative number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
while()
{...read(fd, buffer + bytesRead, sizeof(buffer) - bytesRead);}
```

This line is a major problem. Basically this attempts to store the entire file in to `buffer`. But `buffer` has a small size (256 bytes).

If file is too large, `read` will store 256 in to `buffer` in the first pass. In the second pass in the loop, `read` will attempt to add another 256 bytes to the same buffer.

Instead you have to read small chunks and write back within the loop.

```
fPtr = fopen("log.txt", "w+");
```

This will open the log file in read/write mode, but you only need to write to it. Since this is a log file, consider using `"a"` option to append to the log file.

```
fprintf(fout, "%s", buffer);
```

When you read the buffer it may not be null terminated. Try `fwrite` instead, or make sure `buffer` is null terminated before using `fprintf`

```
#define BUFFER_LENGTH 256
int main()
{
    int fd = open("/dev/show_log_device_dev", O_RDONLY);
    if(fd == -1)
    { perror("open failed"); return 0; }

    FILE* fout = fopen("log.txt", "w"); //or "a" to create new file
    if(fout == NULL)
    { close(fd); perror("fopen failed, log.txt is busy!"); return 0; }

    while (1) 
    {
        char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
        int ret = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (ret == 0)
            break;
        if (ret == -1) 
        {
            perror("Failed to read the message from the device.");
            return errno;
        }
        fwrite(buffer, 1, ret, fout);
        //fprintf(fout, "%s", buffer);
    }

    fclose(fout);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Note, `lseek(fPtr,0,SEEK_SET)` is wrong and not necessary. This method is excepts a file descriptor obtained from `open`. But `fPtr` is `FILE*` handle obtained from `fopen`.

If possible, consider using standard c functions `FILE*/fopen` for both input and output. This way you will be able to use the same set of functions `fopen`,`fread`,`fwrite`,`fclose`,`fseek`,`ftell`. You only need one header file for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fin = fopen("/dev/show_log_device_dev", "r");
    if (!fin)
    { perror("input error"); return 0; }

    FILE* fout = fopen("log.txt", "w"); //or "a" to append to log
    if (!fout) 
    {fclose(fin); perror("output error, log.txt is busy!"); return 0; }

    while (1)
    {
        char buffer[256];
        int ret = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fin);
        if (ret == 0)
            break;
        fwrite(buffer, 1, ret, fout);
    }

    fclose(fout);
    fclose(fin);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the detailed explanation!

Comment: An answer should not merely refer to comments for information about why something is wrong. It should explain. Comments are ephemeral and may vanish at any moment.

Comment: @EricPostpischil My answer had little to do with comments. I only backed up the `lseek` comments. A failed `lseek` attempt doesn't change the program's output. Anyway, updated the answer.

Comment: Updated, address `fopen` method for input. Changed output to `"w"`, you can change to `"a"` if append is needed.