# how do I know if binary file is empty in C

Tags: c, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get a file's size in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238603/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c)

how do I know if binary file is empty in C?

Comment: Check if size is zero, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238603/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c

Comment: empty as in 0, or empty as in doesn't execute any code?

Comment: @Yasir: this can be done portably.

Comment: windows 7 and I mean to check with function of reading files.

Comment: Are you concerned about NTFS alternate streams?

Comment: no I mean to check if exe file for example is emtpy

Answer (score 5):

```
// assume file is opened as FILE *fp
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
bool empty = ftell(fp) == 0L;
```