# Error checking when finding file length using stat

Tags: c, linux, stat

This question is in reference to [How can I get a file's size in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238603/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c)

Most answers suggesting the use of the function stat to get the file length also comes with a tag to do error checking.

What kind of error checking do we need here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like many Unix/POSIX API functions, [`stat(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/stat.2.html) returns a negative integer on failure. Unfortunately, this integer is always -1 for stat. Hence, you need to check the [`errno` global variable](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/errno.3.html) (defined in `<errno.h>`) to see what the exact error was.

[Ben has listed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561082/regarding-finding-file-length-using-stat/6561088#6561088) some of the errors you can run into; the errno codes for these and other errors are listed in the [stat manpage](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/stat.2.html).

Comment: Please avoid giving pagerank to linux.die.net. It has very outdated manpages and is completely unmaintained. The copies on kernel.org are authoritative for Linux.

Comment: R..: All right! I'll fix it! Geez, it's not such a tragedy (unless there are specific errors in the stat(2) and errno(3) manpages that need fixing). I'd just like a webified manual page that doesn't look like someone just wrapped the output of `nroff -man` in a pre tag...

Comment: No need to get upset. I didn't -1 or anything, I just suggested changing it and even said "please". :-)

Answer (score 2):

- The file might not exist
- You might not have permission to access its metadata
- A network mount point might be unreachable, or there could be some other read error
- It might be a special file (device node, for example, or fifo) that doesn't have a size