# C++ stat.h incomplete type and cannot be defined

Tags: c++, filesize, stat, incomplete-type

I am having a very strange issue with stat.h

At the top of my code, I have declarations:

```
#include <sys\types.h> 
#include <sys\stat.h>
```

And function prototype:

```
int FileSize(string szFileName);
```

Finally, the function itself is defined as follows:

```
int FileSize(string szFileName)
{
  struct stat fileStat; 
  int err = stat( szFileName.c_str(), &fileStat ); 
  if (0 != err) return 0; 
  return fileStat.st_size;
}
```

When I attempt to compile this code, I get the error:

```
divide.cpp: In function 'int FileSize(std::string)':
divide.cpp:216: error: aggregate 'stat fileStat' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
divide.cpp:217: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct stat'
divide.cpp:216: error: forward declaration of 'struct stat'
```

From this thread: [How can I get a file's size in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238603/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c)
I think this code should work and I cannot figure out why it does not compile.  Can anybody spot what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same problem although i use correct path separator. I'm compiling with MinGW on Windows, and the compiler has sys/stat.h file with struct stat and function stat declared. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are your `\`'s supposed to be `/`'s or am I just confused about your environment?

UNIX MAN page:

```
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/stat.h>

 int stat(const char *restrict path, struct stat *restrict buf);
```

If you're on Windows (which I'm guessing you might be because of the `\`'s), then I can't help because I didn't even know that had `stat`.

Comment: Ah, the problem is \ instead of / in the include section of the code.  After that fix, the problem was solved.