# Fast, Simple CSV Parsing in C++

Tags: c++, csv, standard-library

I am trying to parse a simple CSV file, with data in a format such as:

```
20.5,20.5,20.5,0.794145,4.05286,0.792519,1
20.5,30.5,20.5,0.753669,3.91888,0.749897,1
20.5,40.5,20.5,0.701055,3.80348,0.695326,1
```

So, a very simple and fixed format file. I am storing each column of this data into a STL vector. As such I've tried to stay the C++ way using the standard library, and my implementation within a loop looks something like:

```
string field;
getline(file,line);
stringstream ssline(line);

getline( ssline, field, ',' );
stringstream fs1(field);
fs1 >> cent_x.at(n);

getline( ssline, field, ',' );
stringstream fs2(field);
fs2 >> cent_y.at(n);

getline( ssline, field, ',' );
stringstream fs3(field);
fs3 >> cent_z.at(n);

getline( ssline, field, ',' );
stringstream fs4(field);
fs4 >> u.at(n);

getline( ssline, field, ',' );
stringstream fs5(field);
fs5 >> v.at(n);

getline( ssline, field, ',' );
stringstream fs6(field);
fs6 >> w.at(n);
```

The problem is, this is extremely slow (there are over 1 million rows per data file), and seems to me to be a bit inelegant. Is there a faster approach using the standard library, or should I just use stdio functions? It seems to me this entire code block would reduce to a single fscanf call.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate of the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/csv-parser-in-c

Comment: C CSV Parser: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cccsvparser C CSV Writer: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cccsvwriter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using 7 string streams when you can do it with just one sure doesn't help wrt. performance.
Try this instead:

```
string line;
getline(file, line);

istringstream ss(line);  // note we use istringstream, we don't need the o part of stringstream

char c1, c2, c3, c4, c5;  // to eat the commas

ss >> cent_x.at(n) >> c1 >>
      cent_y.at(n) >> c2 >>
      cent_z.at(n) >> c3 >>
      u.at(n) >> c4 >>
      v.at(n) >> c5 >>
      w.at(n);
```

If you know the number of lines in the file, you can resize the vectors prior to reading and then use `operator[]` instead of `at()`. This way you avoid bounds checking and thus gain a little performance.

Comment: Perfect! It works much, much better. Thanks for the hint about the chars for eating the commas!

Comment: @KyleLynch: I would seriously advise that you check the `char` were initialized to commas. Also, you should be checking that the stream is valid OR set the exceptions flags, to be warned in case of bad output.

Comment: tiny thing: one char to eat the commas would be sufficient

Comment: What include is needed for input string stream? Why is it not mentioned in the code?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the major bottleneck (put aside the getline()-based non-buffered I/O) is the string parsing. Since you have the "," symbol as a delimiter, you may perform a linear scan over the string and replace all "," by "\0" (the end-of-string marker, zero-terminator).

Something like this:

```
// tmp array for the line part values
double parts[MAX_PARTS];

while(getline(file, line))
{
    size_t len = line.length();
    size_t j;

    if(line.empty()) { continue; }

    const char* last_start = &line[0];
    int num_parts = 0;

    while(j < len)
    {
        if(line[j] == ',')
        {
           line[j] = '\0';

           if(num_parts == MAX_PARTS) { break; }

           parts[num_parts] = atof(last_start);
           j++;
           num_parts++;
           last_start = &line[j];
        }
        j++;
    }

    /// do whatever you need with the parts[] array
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will be quicker than the accepted answer, but I might as well post it anyway in case you wish to try it.
You can load in the entire contents of the file using a single read call by knowing the size of the file using some [fseek magic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238603/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c) This will be much faster than multiple read calls.

You could then do something like this to parse your string:

```
//Delimited string to vector
vector<string> dstov(string& str, string delimiter)
{
  //Vector to populate
  vector<string> ret;
  //Current position in str
  size_t pos = 0;
  //While the the string from point pos contains the delimiter
  while(str.substr(pos).find(delimiter) != string::npos)
  {
    //Insert the substring from pos to the start of the found delimiter to the vector
    ret.push_back(str.substr(pos, str.substr(pos).find(delimiter)));
    //Move the pos past this found section and the found delimiter so the search can continue
    pos += str.substr(pos).find(delimiter) + delimiter.size();
  }
  //Push back the final element in str when str contains no more delimiters
  ret.push_back(str.substr(pos));
  return ret;
}

string rawfiledata;

//This call will parse the raw data into a vector containing lines of
//20.5,30.5,20.5,0.753669,3.91888,0.749897,1 by treating the newline
//as the delimiter
vector<string> lines = dstov(rawfiledata, "\n");

//You can then iterate over the lines and parse them into variables and do whatever you need with them.
for(size_t itr = 0; itr < lines.size(); ++itr)
  vector<string> line_variables = dstov(lines[itr], ",");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::ifstream file{ InputFilename };
std::vector<std::string> line_elements;
for (std::string line; std::getline(file, line);)
{
    line_elements.clear();
    std::istringstream ss(line);
    for (std::string value; std::getline(ss, value, ',');)
    {
        line_elements.push_back(std::move(value));
    }
    // Do something with the line_elements.
}
```