# Size in kbytes of AVI of video in C++/OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there a way to know the size of an avi video in OpenCV? There are some videos that are blank and instead of processing them I want to get rid of them by comparing their size to a threshold. For example, if the size of the video is 200 kB or less, then I skip processing that video.

Update:

```
     CvCapture *capture = cvCreateFileCapture(path);
     IplImage *img = cvQueryFrame( capture );
```

All videos have the same number of frames but some videos have all blank frames.

Comment: What data structure are you reading it as? cvCapture?

Comment: CvCapture *capture = cvCreateFileCapture(path);
IplImage *imgsize = cvQueryFrame( capture );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get number of frames by getting `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT` video property using [GetCaptureProperty](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv.GetCaptureProperty):

> CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT Number of frames in the video file.

To get size of file (video) there is another API - depends on your system (WinAPI, POSIX etc).
For example on Windows it's `GetFileSizeEx()` function.

Also look at this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238603/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c).

Comment: All the videos have the same number of frames. But some videos have all frames blank.

Comment: @bestnagi anyway OpenCV is not a I/O library - use another libs/APIs.

Comment: @bestnagi Blank frames, meaning the entire frame is black?

Comment: yes all videos have 50 frames. but some videos have all frames black/blank.

Comment: @bestnagi it's impossible in OpenCV - OpenCV created to solve another problems.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the fseek method from the SO discussion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the actual file size, you will have to use `fopen()` or `stat` as OpenCV doesn't store this information in a `cvCapture` object.  However, you can detect blank videos like so:

```
CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromAVI( argv[1] );
int numFrames = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(&capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
```

Then just decide if it's blank based on the number of frames.

Relevant Documentation:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=cvcapture#getcaptureproperty

If the file size is different for the blank videos, but the files have the same number of frames, it's due to video compression via keyframing. That means the best way to detect blank frames is via getting the file size, which is outside of the scope of OpenCV and can easily be accomplished using plain C/C++:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
...
struct stat st;
stat(avi_filename, &st);
size = st.st_size;
```

Comment: I had the same answer - what is new in your answer?

Comment: All the videos have same number of frames 50. But some videos have blank frames. Each frame is black.

Comment: @Astor I use OpenCV in Python and I am currently reading the book for C/C++ and I don't need to Google it because there's documentation. You seem to care more about your reputation than helping the OP....

Comment: @AlexW my answer is the same as yours so why did you answer it? I have to copy/paste code from that SO link to help OP or what?

Comment: I ended up using the fseek method. Thanks for your help.