# getting string from file

Tags: c, string, file, get

Why is the output of this code is some random words in memory?

```
void conc()
{
    FILE *source = fopen("c.txt", "r+");
    if(!source)
    {
        printf("Ficheiro não encontrado");
        return;
    }

    short i = 0;
    while(fgetc(source) != EOF)
        i++;

    char tmp_str[i];
    fgets(tmp_str, i, source);
    fclose(source);
    printf("%s", tmp_str);
}
```

This should give me the content of the file, I think.

Comment: Did you compiled your application ?

Comment: is your `while` loop as intended?

Answer (score 7):

Because after you have walked through the file using `fgetc()`, then the position indicator is at end-of-file. `fgets()` has nothing to read. You need to reset it so that it points to the beginning using `rewind(source);`.

By the way, don't loop through the file using `fgetc()`, that's an extremely ugly solution. use [`fseek()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/fseek.html) and [`ftell()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/ftell.html) or [`lseek()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/lseek.html) instead to get the size of the file:

```
fseek(source, SEEK_END, 0);
long size = ftell(source);
fseek(source, SEEK_SET, 0); // or rewind(source);
```

alternative:

```
off_t size = lseek(source, SEEK_END, 0);
rewind(source);
```

Comment: @TelmoVaz You're welcome. BTW, don't loop through the file twice, use `ftell()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rewind(source);` before  `fgets(tmp_str, i, source);`

Answer (score 0):

After your `fgetc()` - loop you have reached EOF and if you don't `fseek( source, 0l, SEEK_SET )` back to the beginning you won't get any more data. 
Anyway you should avoid reading the file twice. Use `fstat( fileno(source), ... )` instead to determine the file size.

Answer (score 0):

fgetc reads a character from the stream. 
fgets reads a string from the stream.

Now in your code you are iterating through the end of the file. So the call to fgets on the stream will simply return NULL and leave the buffer content unchanged. In your case, your buffer is not initialised. This explains the random values you are seeing.

Instead of reading the complete file content with fgetc to get the character count, I recommend using fseek / ftell (see answer from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238603/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c))

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. As was said before:

1. You should not read file twice
2. To allocate array dynamically you must use operator new (in c++)
   or function malloc (in c)

If you need code to read content of the file, try next (sorry, but I didn't compile it. anyway it should work well):

```
FILE* source = fopen("c.txt", "r+b");
if(!source){return;}
fseek(source, 0, SEEK_END);
size_t filesize = ftell(source);
fseek(source, 0, SEEK_SET);
char* buf = new char[filesize+1]; // +1 is for '/0'
fread(buf, sizeof(char), filesize, source);
fclose(source);
buf[filesize]=0;
printf("%s", buf);
delete buf;
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call fgetc() you advance the internal file pointer one character further. At the end of your while() loop the file pointer will then be at the end of the file. Subsequent calls intented to read on the file handle will fail with an EOF condition.

The fgets manual says that :

> > If the end-of-file is encountered while attempting to read a character, the eof indicator is set (feof). If this happens before any characters could be read, the pointer returned is a null pointer (and the contents of str remain unchanged).

The consequence is that tmp_str is left unchanged. The garbage you get back when you call printf is actually a part of the conc() function stack.

A solution to your problem would be rewinding the file pointer with fseek() just before calling fgets().

```
fseek(source, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Then a better way to get the size of your file would be to fseek to the end of the file, and use ftell to get the current position :

```
long size;
fseek(source, 0, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(source);
```

This being said, your code still has a problem. When you allocate on the stack (variables local to a function) you have to tell the size of the variable at compile time. Here your compiler allocates a char array of length 0. I suggest you investigate dynamic allocation with *malloc* of the keyword *new* if you're coding in C++.

A proper allocation would look like this :

```
char *tmp_str = malloc(size);
// Here you read the file
free(tmp_str);
```

An simpler solution could be to preallocate a string large enough to hold your file.

```
char tmp_str[1024 * 100]; // 100Kb
```

Then use the *size* variable we got earlier to check the file will fit in tmp_str before reading.