# Why the ftell returns 0 in this function?

Tags: c, ftell

When I run my program and I choose to see the product list, it doesn't print anything. After some time, I find out that the value of `fl_size` is always 0.  Why is this?

```
void view_prdct_code_list() {
        FILE *stock = fopen("stock.dat","r+");
        assert(stock);

        int fl_size=ftell(stock);
        int prd_size= sizeof(product);
        int quantity= fl_size/prd_size;
        printf("fl_size=%d",fl_size);

        fseek(stock,0,SEEK_SET);
        prdct cprd= (product *)malloc (sizeof(product)*quantity);
        assert(cprd);

        int i;

        fread(cprd,prd_size,quantity,stock);

        for (i=0;i<quantity;i++){
                printf("PRODUCT CODE: %d\n",cprd->code);
        }

        free(cprd);
        fclose(stock);
}
```

Comment: OT: `ftell()` returns a `long`, so you'd better use a `long` to store its result, but an `int`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ftell` does not return the total size of the file; it returns the current *read or write position* within the file.  You call `ftell` immediately after opening the file, so that position is the very beginning of the file.  You can either use `fseek(stock, 0, SEEK_END)` to seek to the end before calling `ftell`, or you can drop down a layer and use `fstat(fileno(stock))` to retrieve the file size directly from the OS.

Further notes:

1. Neither of these options will work if you are reading from a pipe.  (In general, you need to check for the success of every single one of your file access operations.)
2. `fread` is not guaranteed to read the entire file in one gulp even if you ask it to.
3. As 'alk' points out, `ftell` returns a `long`, not an `int`.
4. If `long` is only 32 bits, it is possible for a file to be so large that its size does not fit in a `long`.  If your program needs to handle files that big, you need to `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` at the top of every `.c` file (before all the includes) and use `fseeko` and `ftello`. (Or whatever the Windows equivalent is.)
5. You should be opening this apparently-binary file with mode `"r+b"`.
6. Binary files with no file header (and in particular with no [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29), of at least four bytes, at offset zero) are a Bad Thing.
7. Do not cast the return value of `malloc`.  (It is necessary to do this in C++, but in C it is not only unnecessary, *it can hide bugs*.)

Answer (score 3):

Check man page for `ftell`, for example this one: http://linux.die.net/man/3/ftell

Here is the relevant part: *"The ftell() function obtains the current value of the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by stream."*

When you open the file, cursor position will be at the start. So distance from start will be zero. Therefore `ftell` returns zero.

To find the size of file, see this link: [How can I get a file's size in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238603/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c). Here's a snippet in short:

```
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
sz = ftell(fp);
```

Make sure to call `fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);` after above.

Comment: With any modern C library (and by "modern" I mean "C89 compliant") you can write `0` instead of `0L`.  The L was only necessary with C libraries that didn't provide a prototype for `fseek`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `ftell` returns the size from the beginning to the current position of the file.

```
fseek(stock,0,SEEK_SET);
```

Means you set the position to the first bite of the file.

Also you gotta set `fl_size=ftell(stock);` **after** the `fseek`.

Comment: Shouldn't `fseek(stock,0,SEEK_SET);` be `fseek(stock,0L,SEEK_END);`? i.e. go to end of file and then count position. This post doesn't seems like correct answer.

Comment: To be honest i just use `fseek(stock,0,SEEK_END);` when counting the still size Thats why i forgot to specify the offset. Plus im just quoting.