# Malloc() and free() stopping me from passing structs by value in C

Tags: c, ansi-c

I'm working on a project and I keep getting segmentation faults, and the values of the structs aren't being passed. Figuring out why is driving my crazy. I've tried figuring out the problem with simpler programs, and I think I've found the problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

The problem is that when I "malloc" a struct, THEN pass by value, the value is lost. Adding "free" later produces a segmentation fault. I'm not trying to access a value from before the "malloc()" or after the "free()", so I'm confused as to why this is happening.

Here's a simple model of the problem:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

    struct structexample
    {
        int element;
    };

    void initStruct(struct structexample * teststruct, int * number)
    {
        teststruct = malloc(sizeof(struct structexample)); 
        teststruct->element = 10;
        printf("teststruct element is %d in initStruct\n", teststruct->element);
        *number = 5;
    }

    void printtest(struct structexample * teststruct, int * number)
    {
        printf("teststruct element is %d in printtest\n", teststruct->element);
        printf("Number is %d\n", *number);
        free(teststruct);
    }

int main()
{
    int number;
    struct structexample teststruct;
    initStruct(&teststruct, &number);
    printtest(&teststruct, &number);
    printf("teststruct element is %d in main()", teststruct.element);
    return 0;
}
```

This produces:

```
teststruct element is 10 in initStruct
teststruct element is -7967792 in printtest
Number is 5
Segmentation fault
```

I compile the program with "gcc -Wall -pedantic -ansi" and get no errors or warnings there.

When I comment out "malloc" and "free" it correctly produces:

```
teststruct element is 10 in initStruct
teststruct element is 10 in printtest
Number is 5
```

If I only comment out "free" but leave "malloc" in, that fixes the segmentation fault, but the values of the structs are still incorrect. In this simple program I don't really need "malloc()" and "free()", but I do need them in my larger project. If I can make them work in this simpler program, then I think I can fix the larger one. I can't find a similar problem on Google unfortunately.

Comment: Ansi C is obsolete. Use C99 or C11. Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and perhaps `-std=c99`). If on Linux, learn about [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and use `gdb` (it has watchpoints).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void initStruct(struct structexample * teststruct, int * number)
{
    teststruct = malloc(sizeof(struct structexample)); 
    teststruct->element = 10;
    printf("teststruct element is %d in initStruct\n", teststruct->element);
    *number = 5;
}
```

You pass this function a value, the address of a structure, which it totally ignores. It allocates with `malloc`, but does nothing with the address it got back. It doesn't return it. It doesn't put it anywhere other code can get it. So you've just leaked this object.

```
void printtest(struct structexample * teststruct, int * number)
{
    printf("teststruct element is %d in printtest\n", teststruct->element);
    printf("Number is %d\n", *number);
    free(teststruct);
}
```

So `printtest` passes `teststruct` to `free`, so it should be passed a value returned from `malloc`.

```
struct structexample teststruct;
initStruct(&teststruct, &number);
printtest(&teststruct, &number);
```

But you pass `printtest` the address of `teststruct`, which is allocated on the stack. That can't be right.

Are you expecting `initStruct` to somehow move `teststruct`? It surely can't do that.

Comment: Ah I think I get it now. "Malloc" changes where the pointer to "teststruct" points to, which is a different one than the one passed into the function. I'm confused about where I should malloc now though. I've written "&teststruct = malloc(sizeof(struct structexample));" outside the function, but that produces the error " lvalue required as left operand of assignment".

Comment: How about `struct structexample* teststruct = malloc ...`?

Comment: I have to split it up into two lines because I can't mix declarations and code, but that works! Thanks.

Comment: I'm having another problem I'm having trouble with. I've added it to this question with an edit. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: What do you think `sizeof(*fp)` does? I think you have a serious misunderstanding about what `sizeof` does. Either that or you don't understand what a `FILE` is -- it's the thing that you use to access an opened file. Since `*fp` is a `FILE`, then `sizeof(*fp)` is saying "how big is this thing that I'm using to access this opened file". What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: I meant for "data" to be the size of the data stored in "fp". I thought a FILE acted like a pointer to a file, so I dereferenced fp in "sizeof()" to attempt to refer to the size of the contents.

Comment: I just read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238603/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c                       

I'm going to try adding that in to see if it works.

Comment: @user5988698 Then you have some misunderstandings about how C types work. The size of something is always a function of its type and always independent of its contents.

Comment: Thanks! I think I've fixed problem, but I'm still having the other problems I mentioned. I've updated my post with a second edit.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but it sounds like you just need to learn C and should probably work on simpler problems so that you don't have to figure out 100 things at once.

Comment: Thanks for the honest feedback, but I'm learning C as part of a course, so I don't really have a choice!

Comment: I'm still trying to figure this out. Are there any tips or hints you could give me to help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing stack and heap

```
void initStruct(struct structexample * teststruct, int * number)
 {
     teststruct = malloc(sizeof(struct structexample)); 
     ^ There is no need to use malloc, teststruct is on the stack

 ...

int main()
{
    int number;
    struct structexample teststruct;
    initStruct(&teststruct, &number);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm having another problem, which I've added to this question with an edit. Could you please help me with this too?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `free()` line from `printtest()` so it looks like this:

```
void printtest(struct structexample * teststruct, int * number)
{
    printf("teststruct element is %d in printtest\n", teststruct->element);
    printf("Number is %d\n", *number);
}
```

The segmentation fault happens because you're trying to free memory that is on the stack !!

You can also remove the `malloc()` line from `initStruct()` because it has no use: it's allocating space for a `struct structexample` and returning it's address into `teststruct` wich is a `struct structexample *` allocated on the heap and passed to `initStruct()`, meaning it will be lost once the call to `initStruct()` returns.

Comment: Thanks! I'm having another problem, which I've added to this question with an edit. Could you please help me with this too?

Comment: If it's reading white space separated words you want, use `fscanf()`, it does that. test for the end of file using `feof()` in a `while` loop to read words using `fscanf()`.