# How to properly malloc and free char** when reading from file (unknown length)?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, malloc

Currently I have the following code below. `char **arr` is initially set to `NULL`. then it stores in words while reading from a file.  I just randomly chose a large number like `5000` because I don't understand how to do `malloc` business properly, even after looking online and trying to learn.

Also, when I try to `free` `char **arr` (the last section of my code), sometimes I get `segmentation faults`, sometimes `abort traps`, etc. If someone could show me how to do something like this properly that would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

```
char **arr = NULL 

File *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r")
char string[3000];
char counter = 0; 


//to store
while(fscanf(fp, "%s", string)!=EOF){ 
    arr = realloc(arr, 5000); //arbitrarily used a large number like 5000 
    arr[counter] = malloc(5000); 
    strcpy(arr[counter++], string); 
}

//to free

for(i=0; i<counter; i++){
    free(arr[i])
} 
free(arr);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a file's size in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238603/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c)

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), then **use the debugger** `gdb` and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Read also documentation of [malloc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) and related

Comment: Please provide some [MCVE] with some explanation. Your fix-my-code question is off-topic

Answer (score 4):

Don't use arbitrary numbers.

The size argument passed to [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) is the new number of bytes to allocate. In your case it could be `(counter + 1) * sizeof(char *)` bytes. If the file contains more than around a thousand words then `5000` will not be enough. Not to mention you call `realloc` to not change the size after the first call.

And don't use arbitrary values for the `malloc` call either. Either use `strlen(string) + 1`, or if available then you could use `strdup` instead.

---

Lastly, don't reassign back to the variable you pass as pointer to `realloc`. If `realloc` fails and returns `NULL` you will have lost your original pointer.

Instead use a temporary variable that you check before assigning backt o the original pointer variable:

```
char **temp = realloc(arr, ...);
if (temp == NULL)
{
    // ERRORO: Do something appropriate
}

arr = temp;
```

Comment: I would recommend instead something like a `newsize = 4*oldsize/3+10;` progression, and a `realloc` with `newsize`. Of course the current allocated size should be explicitly kept.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what exactly does the last one mean? Don't reassign back to variable...etc

Comment: @novice Updated with an example

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ah, thanks! So it's basically in the rare event that a realloc doesn't work.

Comment: @novice Yep that's correct. And even rare events needs to be safeguarded against.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Agreed! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) of getline(), this function allocate the line for you if the * is NULL. Use this function could be a proper way to do it instead of using strlen and fscanf.