# C Read file content into string just with stdio libary

Tags: c, linux, file, reader

Im struggleing by trying to read the files content into a string (char*).
I just have to use the stdio.h libary, so I cant allocate memory with malloc.

How can I read all the content of a file and return it into a string?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it.  What specific problem are you trying to overcome?

Comment: Why do you think you need `malloc`?

Comment: sounds like homework

Comment: I wanna create a simple copy & paste script. So what function do I need to get the string.. fscanf needs input format, fgetc gives me just a char.. so what do I need

Comment: Again. Let's assume you *can* use `malloc`. how will you implement it then ?

Comment: You simple need an array of char that is bigger than the biggest file you expect to read.

Comment: I would use fread by referring a buffer to ptr

Comment: _by referring a buffer to ptr_ : what??

Comment: Hint: to get the size of your file read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238603/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c)

Comment: Yea this is using malloc what im trying to avoid

Comment: This question could look legit if you were posting here your solution using `malloc` and asking how to do without it.

Comment: Legit ?? Why should a question look legit lol: char * content= 0;
  int length;
  fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
  length = ftell(file);
  fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
  content = malloc(length);
  if (content){
   fread(content, 1, length, file);
  }
  fclose(file);

  return content;

Comment: @reByte:  ALWAYS put code into your question, never in a comment unless it is a simple, short statement.

Comment: If you can't use `malloc` you need to define an array of `char` large enough to hold the file contents. If you can determine the file size and are allowed to define a variable-length array (VLA) you could define one of those.

Comment: If you're reading the file into a string you should `malloc` one byte extra so you have space to store the `NUL` and also add it as `fread` won't do it for you

Comment: Please explain what exactly you're having. Do you have a pointer pointing to a memory whose size is guaranteed to be at least the file size and a NUL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will attempt to answer your question. Keep in mind though - I am still fairly new to C, so there could be a better solution out there in which case please let me know about it too! :)

EDIT: And there was...

Here is how I see it... 
You need to know the size of the file you want to store in a string. 
More precisely - in the example solution that I'm providing, you need to know how many chars are in your input file.

All you are doing with `malloc` is dynamically allocating memory on the 'heap'. I presume you already know that...
So regardless of where your `string` lives in memory (stack or heap) you need to know how big that `string` has to be, so all of the contents of your input file would fit in to it.

Here is a quick pseudo-code and some code with a solution to your problem... I hope this is helpful and I am open to learn a better approach if there is one, peace!

Pseudo-code:

1. open input file for reading
2. find out the size of the file

   > - forward seek file position indicator to the end of the file
   > - get the total number of bytes (chars) in infile
   > - rewind file position indicator back to the start
   >     (because we will be reading from it again)
3. declare a char array, size of - all counted chars in infile + 1 for '\0' 
   at the end of the string.
4. read all chars of infile in to the array
5. Terminate your string with '\0'
6. Close input file

Here is a simple program that does just that and prints your string:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Open input file
    FILE *infile = fopen("hello.py", "r");
    if (!infile)
    {
        printf("Failed to open input file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////
    // Getting file size

    // seek file position indicator to the end of the file
    fseek(infile, 0L, SEEK_END);

    // get the total number of bytes (chars) in infile
    int size = ftell(infile); // ask for the position

    // Rewind file position indicator back to the start of the file
    rewind(infile);

    //////////////////////////////////

    // Declaring a char array, size of - all the chars from input file + 1 for the '\0'
    char str[size + 1];

    // Read all chars of infile in to the array
    fread(&str, sizeof(char), size, infile);

    // Terminate the string
    str[size] = '\0'; // since we are zero indexed 'size' happens to be the last element of our array[size + 1]

    printf("%s\n", str);

    // Close the input file
    fclose(infile);

    // The end
    return 0;

}
```