# How to read string from file into dynamic array in c?

Tags: c

I have the following program below that compiles without error. My goal is to read the contents of a file into an array called str. However, this array needs to be dynamic and memory must be reallocated each line, as the file length is unknown.

```c
int i;
char *str;
    
FILE *fptr = fopen(filename,"r"); //Open the required file in read mode
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), fptr);
    printf("%s", str);
}
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: 1. Where does `str` point to? 2. What do you think the value of `sizeof(str)` is?

Comment: Also a good idea to check the return value from `fopen`

Comment: Can you define a maximum line length?  4096, say?  You can then realloc down after a read.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238603/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c) might help

Comment: Any introductory C course or beginner's website will cover this elementary material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the file's length by using `fseek` to move to the end of the file, then `ftell` to read the current position (which is the same as the files length (in bytes)), and lastly use `rewind` to restore the file pointer to the head of the file:

```
fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END);
file_length = ftell(fptr);
rewind(fptr);
```

Once you know the file's length, you can dynamically allocate an array large enough to hold it. Here is a complete example:

```
FILE *fptr;
long str_length;
char *str;

// Open the file.
fptr = fopen(filename, "rb");

// Get the size of the file.
fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END);
str_length = ftell(fptr);
rewind(fptr);

// Allocate memory to contain the whole file including the null byte.
str = calloc(str_length + 1, sizeof(char)); // +1 for null byte.

// Read the contents of the file into the buffer.
fread(str, 1, str_length, fptr);

// Null terminate the string.
str[str_length] = '\0';

// Close the file.
fclose(fptr);

// Print the contents of the file.
printf("%s", str);
```

This example does not include error checking.

Comment: Please add a check for the return value for `fopen`

Comment: *You can calculate the file's length by using `fseek` to move to the end of the file...* [Not portably](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note268): "Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)`, has undefined behavior for a binary stream..."  [Also](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.2p3): "A binary stream need not meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a `whence` value of `SEEK_END`."  I'm betting whoever taught you to use `fseek()`/`ftell()` to get the size of a file left that out.

Comment: You could do `struct stat buf; long length = fstat(fileno(fptr,) &buf) == 0 ? buf.st_size : 0`

Comment: @EdHeal You are correct, I am not checking return values, but `fopen` isn't the only function that should be checked. I intentionally omitted error checking (as noted in my answer) to keep it compact.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yup, on POSIX you can use `stat` as @EdHeal suggested and on Windows use `GetFileSize`.

Comment: @hgs3 - At least add it to the comment `open file`...etc

Answer (score 0):

On a POSIX system, you can use `getline`:

```
FILE *fptr = fopen(filename,"r"); //Open the required file in read mode
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    char *str = 0;
    int len = 0;
    if (getline(&str, &len, fptr) > 0) {
        printf("%s", str);
        free(str); }
}
```