# Trying to print out contents from a file but I get segmentation fault error

Tags: c, file, memory, dynamic, allocation

I am trying to apply dynamic memory allocation on reading text files but I don't really get how I could access the contents of the file. I am still having difficulties understanding memory allocation so if it is possible, please explain how I can apply it on file handling.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void) {
    int counter = 0;
    char ch;
    char **chpt;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF ){
        counter++;
    }
    rewind(fp);

    chpt = (char **)malloc(counter * sizeof(char));

    fread(chpt, counter * sizeof(char), 1, fp);

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++) {
            printf("%c", chpt[i][j]);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    free(chpt);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your nested for loops don't make any sense and you're trying to print `counter*counter` characters, but you have only read `counter` characters. You don't have a 2D array here, and you don't need one either.

Furthermore:

- you need to check if `fopen` fails
- the cast with `malloc` is not needed (but it doesn't harm either)

Your file contains obviously `counter` characters. So you need to allocate memory for `counter` characters, read `counter` characters from the file, and then display the `counter` characters you've just read.

You want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  int counter = 0;
  char ch;
  char* chpt;      // just a pointer to char
  FILE* fp;

  fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
  if (f == NULL)                 // check if fopen failed
  {
    printf("Can't open file\n");   // print error message
    return 1;                    // and abort
  }

  while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    counter++;
  }
  rewind(fp);

  chpt = malloc(counter * sizeof(char));  // no cast needed

  fread(chpt, counter * sizeof(char), 1, fp);

  for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {     // one loop is enough
      printf("%c", chpt[i]);
  }

  fclose(fp);
  free(chpt);
  return 0;
}
```

There is still room for further improvement:

- you should check if `malloc` fails, even if it's unlikely to fail if the file isn't huge
- your method of determining the file size is very inefficient, for more information read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/238607/898348)
- `sizeof(char)` is not needed, it is 1 by definition.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! and wow... I have really grossly misunderstood pointers and addresses.... but I totally get what you are saying now I'll make sure to read more.....