# How to get the file length in C on Linux?

Tags: linux, file, io, filesize

I'm looking for the equivalent of Microsoft's [_filelength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfbc2kec.aspx) in Linux. I tried this, but it's incorrect.

```
long _filelength(char *f)
{
    struct stat st;
    stat(f, &st);
    return st.st_size;
}

if((hfile = fopen("data.arp","rb"))!=NULL)
    fsize = _filelength(fileno(hfile));
```

How do I get the file length in C on Linux?

Comment: What makes you think that it is incorrect? It does not compile!

Comment: I think `fsize = _filelength(fileno(hfile));` --> `fsize = _filelength(hfile);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you determine the size of a file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8236/608639), [How can I get a file's size in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/238603/608639), [Proper way to get file size in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35390912/608639), [How to get a file length in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1669676/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FILE *fp = fopen("filename", "rb");
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
int lengthOfFile = ftell(fp);
fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm looking for the equivalent of _filelength in linux.

That is a very **wrong approach** and shows a wrong mindset. **There is no exact equivalent of Windows' `_filelength` on Linux**. Linux is *not* Windows and Windows is not Linux. Each operating system has its own [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) and its own vision of files (On Linux, they are inodes, see [inode(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49473248/841108) answer...), processes etc.... Linux is mostly POSIX compliant, so study POSIX and read some book on Linux system programming, perhaps the old [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) or something newer. Don't expect (and don't even try) to find an equivalent of every Windows or [WinAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) function on Linux. See [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html), [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [intro(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/intro.3.html).

Read more carefully [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html). It takes a string (some file path), not a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) (like `fstat` does) as the one given by [fileno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html). It can fail (and you need to understand why, probably using [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html), which is never negative).

BTW, identifiers with a name starting with `_` are reserved.

Perhaps you might try:

```
long filelength(const char*filpath) { // don't use that. Learn POSIX API
   struct stat st;
   if (stat(filpath, &st)) /*failure*/
      return -1; // when file does not exist or is not accessible
   return (long) st.st_size;
}
```

but in practice you'll better use `stat` directly in your program (and **check [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) on failure**, not just simply returning -1 like I did above), and you probably should use the *other* metadata returned by `stat` in it.

Linux (and Unix) also have [sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file), [hard links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link), [device files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file), [symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), anonymous files (e.g. still opened inodes, but no more present in the file system), [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)-s, [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) sockets, etc.... You probably need to handle them (but they don't have an exact equivalent on Windows).

Read also [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

You might use multi-platform frameworks like [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/) or [Boost](http://boost.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.io/). They are trying to provide some common [abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)) above several operating systems (but some details still matter and are difficult to hide or to abstract; for example a file [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) is not the same on Windows and on Linux. See [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html)...)

You should compile with all warnings and debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). You might also use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand the [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) done by your program.

Comment: Yes. Did you check `errno` ? As I try to explain, you have the wrong approach. Change your mindset to be Linux friendly. Don't think in WinAPI terms. Learn the POSIX API, it is not the same!

Comment: I definitely agree with learning the Linux APIs.  I'm not sure I agree with using them though.  If you're writing code that works on Windows and Linux, you might well want a portability layer, and you might decide your portability layer looks a lot more like winapi than Linux.

Comment: `errno` is never -1. You've got something wrong. Show some [MCVE] in your question.

Comment: Wonderful introduction.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try with this.

```
size_t _filelength(int filedes)
{
    off_t pos = lseek(filedes, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    if (pos != (off_t)-1)
    {
        off_t size = lseek(filedes, 0, SEEK_END);
        lseek(filedes, pos, SEEK_SET);
        return (size_t)size;
    }
    return (off_t)-1;
}
```

Comment: This appears to be the only snap-in replacement for Microsoft's `_filelength`. Important detail: `_filelength` takes a file descriptor of an open file as parameter. Not file path as other answers missed.

Answer (score -1):

You have to seek through the file.

```
fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
```

Then get the current position:

```
fileSize = ftell(file);
```

Then to reset the position back to the beginning use:

```
rewind(file);
```

Comment: That's not strictly-compliant C.  It's [undefined behavior to seek to the end of a binary stream](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note268), and you [can't use `ftell()` to get the size of a text stream in bytes](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.4p2)