# Replacing C code written in win32 into linux based system

Tags: c, macos

I am trying to replicate WIN32 code for MacOSX, however I am unable to replicate a part of code

Here is the code.

```
main_int64 pos;
  OP_ASSERT(sizeof(pos)==sizeof(fpos_t));
  /*Translate the seek to an absolute one.*/
  if(_whence==SEEK_CUR)
  {
    int ret;
    ret=fgetpos((FILE *)_stream,(fpos_t *)&pos);
    if(ret)return ret;
  }
  else if(_whence==SEEK_END)pos=_filelengthi64(_fileno((FILE *)_stream));
  else if(_whence==SEEK_SET)pos=0;
  else return -1;
  /*Check for errors or overflow.*/
  if(pos<0||_offset<-pos||_offset>OP_INT64_MAX-pos)return -1;
  pos+=_offset;

  int seeko = fsetpos((FILE *)_stream,(fpos_t *)&pos);
  fprintf("BaseTool", "SEEKO VALUE %d \n", seeko);
  return seeko;
```

I am stuck at

> else `if(_whence==SEEK_END)pos=_filelengthi64(_fileno((FILE
>   *)_stream));`

I am not sure how can I replace these functions in mac based system as these are WIN based functions

Comment: MacOSX is not Linux, but both are (nearly) POSIX. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50119218/841108) answer to a nearly duplicate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the code I understand you are trying to get the length of the file, in linux you can do this way,

```
 int fp           = open("check5.c", O_RDONLY);
off_t lengthOfFile = lseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
close(fp);
printf("%d",lengthOfFile);
```

So replace it with "lseek(fileno,0, SEEK_END)" should give length of the file.

Comment: I would recommend using [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) instead.

Comment: Yeah stat should work as well. But for this lseek also should work

Comment: It won't work if `check5.c` was not a plain file, but e.g. a fifo... And your `lseek` trick would give strange results if `check5.c` is written at the same time by some other process.