# off_t without -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 on a file > 2GB

Tags: c, file, large-files

1- I'm wondering, what would be the problem if I try to read a file greater than `2GB` in size without compiling my program with the option `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` using `off_t` and using the second function on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236/how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file-in-c/8384#8384)? would it segfault?

2- I'm planning to use [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236/how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file-in-c/8384#8384) with `off64_t` and

```
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE 1
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
```

Would there be any problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. [stat()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/stat.html) will fail, and errno set
   to  EOVERFLOW in that case. Here's
   what the linux man page says

   > ```
   > EOVERFLOW  stat()) path refers to a file whose size cannot be
   > represented in the type off_t.  This can occur when an application
   > ```
   >
   > compiled
   >       on a 32-bit  platform  without  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 calls stat() on a
   >       file whose size exceeds (2<<31)-1 bits.
2. If you compile with -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 , you don't need to use off64_t though. 
     You can just continue to use off_t , it'll become 64 bit, and all the functions
     dealing with files and file sizes will become 64 bit aware.

Answer (score 1):

Never use `off64_t` explicitly. Always build your programs with 64 bit file offsets on systems where it's necessary to explicitly specify this. Failure to do so is a major bug which your users will end up hating. No idea why it's not default on modern systems...

Answer (score -1):

It oughtn't segfault, but the size of the file won't be reported correctly.