# c copy files in reverse order using lseek

Tags: c, file, posix, filestream

I've got how to copy one file to another from start, but how could i modify the programme to copy it in reverse order? Source file should have read access and destination file read write execute. I have to use file control libraries.

for example

```
FILE A            File B should be
|---------|        |----------|
|ABCDEF   |        |FEDCBA    |
|---------|        |----------|
```

************************************UPDATE***********************

Thank you, MikeNakis for hints and suggestions
           ,Sangeeth for your code

I've reworked the code and now it is copy bytes in reverse order printing filesize

here is the code

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int source, dest, n;
    char buf;
    int filesize;
    int i;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage %s <source> <dest>", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    if ((source = open(argv[1], 0400)) < 0) { //read permission for user on source
        fprintf(stderr, "can't open source");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if ((dest = creat(argv[2], 0700)) < 0) { //rwx permission for user on dest
        fprintf(stderr, "can't create dest");
        exit(-1);
    }

    filesize = lseek(source, (off_t) 0, SEEK_END); //filesize is lastby +offset
    printf("Source file size is %d\n", filesize);

    for (i = filesize - 1; i >= 0; i--) { //read byte by byte from end
        lseek(source, (off_t) i, SEEK_SET);

        n = read(source, &buf, 1);

        if (n != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "can't read 1 byte");
            exit(-1);
        }

        n = write(dest, &buf, 1);
        if (n != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "can't write 1 byte");
            exit(-1);
        }

    }
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "DONE\n", 5);
    close(source);
    close(dest);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in reverse order" ?

Comment: copy file from the end like 

file A |abcdefg|
file B should be copied |gfedcba|

Comment: OK - so you want to reverse the order of the *bytes* in the destination file ?

Comment: do you mean, string reverse the whole file content and write it into a new file?!

Comment: Paul R. Yes I think you got me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just seek to the end and start reading from there. No wonder it won't read anything. You need to seek to the end minus 1 byte, read one byte, write it, then seek to the end minus two bytes, read another byte, and so on.

I presume this is a homework assignment, so your professor should not mind the extreme inefficiency of this approach. (Real-world performance concerns are oh-so un-academic.) If he complains, tell him that in theory, it has the same time complexity as any other algorithm which would perform the same task: O(N). (That's pronounced "big oh of en".) He will give you an A+.

Comment: so lseek(source,-1,SEEK_END)?

Comment: Then you should care about buffering. Why don't you handle your file several kilobytes at a time?

Comment: lseek(source,-1,SEEK_END) is in the right direction, but that will not work, either. You should use lseek(source,n,SEEK_END), inside a for loop, where n varies starting from -1, while <= -file_size.

Comment: yes i can use buf[100] at time, but i want to understand hot lseek works. I would be glad if you could assist me. So I have 3 file descriptors 
source, dest and buf, 
reading source, putting read position to the end
but what to write in while loop?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch let him get it to work correctly the slow-as-molasses way, and then he may worry about making it more efficient. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Comment: You put the read position where it needs to be, read one byte, and write it to the output file, then move the read position back by 1, and repeat. Until the beginning of the source file.

Comment: so, is this line correct ? while ((n=read(source,&buf,1))!=0) 
how can i loop lseek and increment counter?

Comment: Nope, you should actually assert that you always read 1 byte. For as long as you are reading within the file, reading 1 byte should always succeed.

Comment: for( int i = 0;  i < file_size;  i++ ) { lseek(source,file_size - 1 - i,SEEK_END); ... }

Comment: file_size should be initialized to -1?

Comment: No, you need to somehow find the file size. Look at the functions available in fcntl for a function which returns the file size. Hint: lseek can be used to find the file size.

Comment: StackOverflow is the place for everything: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236/how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file-in-c

Comment: Actually, forget that q&a that I pointed you to. Just use lseek to calculate the length of the file, since you are already using int file handles.

Comment: @MikeNakis By popular words, "Nevermind that the O(x) is actually [a] pretty large O." :)

Comment: MikeNakis, can you edit your answer and add my recent code to your answer, so we can accept it and rate you (:. I will remove mine

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

lseek(source, (off_t) i, SEEK_SET); should probably be lseek(source, (off_t) i - 1, SEEK_SET);