# How can I obtain a file's size in C?

Tags: c, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you determine the size of a file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236/how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file-in-c)

How can I obtain a file's size in C? I opened with an application written in C. I would like to know the size, because I want to put the content of the loaded file into a string, which I alloc using malloc(). Just writing malloc(10000*sizeof(char)

Comment: the stat(2) system call, which a quick google should've told you

Comment: What platform are you targeting? Or do you intend for this to be cross-platform?

Comment: Also, it's already been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238603/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c

Comment: Is it necessary to hold the whole file in memory at the same time?

Comment: wow,it's already been answered in fact! It's my fault,thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the fseek and ftell functions:

```
FILE* f = fopen("try.txt","rb");
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
printf("size of the file is %ld", ftell(f));
```

Comment: +1 for the easy way i also always using. fstat / stat would be the other way.

Answer (score 1):

for file size, stat, lstat or fstat will be the right choice.

pleas check [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat)

Answer (score 0):

```
    int Get_Size( string path )
{

FILE *pFile = NULL;

// get the file stream

fopen_s( &pFile, path.c_str(), "rb" );


// set the file pointer to end of file

fseek( pFile, 0, SEEK_END );

// get the file size

int Size = ftell( pFile );

// return the file pointer to begin of file if you want to read it

rewind( pFile );

// close stream and release buffer

fclose( pFile );

return Size;
}
```

more answers [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/10853/)

Answer (score 0):

You can position yourself at the end of the file with fseek and use ftell() for that:

```
FILE *fd;
fd = fopen("filename.txt","rb");
fseek ( fd, 0 , SEEK_END );
int fileSize = ftell(fd);
```

filesize will contain the size in Bytes.

gekod

Answer (score 0):

I thought there was a standard C function for this, but I couldn't find it.

If your file size is limited, you can use the solution proposed by izomorphius.

If your file can be larger than 2GB then you can use the _filelengthi64 function (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfbc2kec(v=vs.80).aspx).  Unfortunately, this is a Microsoft/Windows function so it's probably not available for other platforms (although you will probably find similar functions on other platforms).

**EDIT:** Look at afge2's answer for the standard C function.  Unfortunately, I think this is still limited to 2GB.