# How to check if a file size is greater than a determined number?

Tags: c, if-statement, fopen, filesize, fclose

I want to use a if statement to check if a file size is greater than a determined number in kb.
For example:

```
if(filesize GTREATER than VARX){
 DO
}else{
 DO
}
```

I'm new to C yet, so please, can you explain clearly, if I have to use a different function.

Comment: You need to get the file size of the file. That has been asked for before on SO, and can be find at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236/how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file-in-c After that, you can compare the size returned against whatever value you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already `fopen()`ed the file, then you can use `fstat()`. `stat()` or `lstat()` can be used on files by name (in a string), but are somewhat less efficient if you do it repeatedly. You'll need to use `fileno()` to get the file descriptor (`int`) from the `FILE *` returned by `fopen()`. Otherwise, the man pages have reasonable examples.

Comment: `fstat`, `stat`, and `fileno` are all POSIX and can work if you're on a system that (at least approximately) supports POSIX functions, but the portable C way to do this is with `fseek` and `ftell`.