# Reading and storing dynamically to char array

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have a file that i want to read from and store the data to a char array that i dynamically allocate memory to after each character read. I want to dynamically allocate memory exactly to that of the size needed. Here is what i have:

```
FILE *fp;
char *data;
int c=0;

fp=fopen("home/bob/Downloads/filename", "r");
data=malloc(sizeof(char));

do{
    data[c]=fgetc(fp);
    printf("data : %c\n", data[c]);
    c++;
    data=realloc(data, sizeof(char)+c);
} while(data[c]!=EOF);
```

I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, `EOF` is *not* a `char` value, it needs `int`. Look at the [prototype for `fgetc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc).

Comment: but then how does using an int variable store the data in the file? some int variable=fgetc(pointer); returns data and stores it into the int variable?

Comment: value from file is a char casted to int or EOF. So you need to read it in int, then check if it's not EOF and then cast it to char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely here:

```
while(data[c]!=EOF)
```

Remember that you *increase* `c` inside the loop, so `data[c]` is an uninitialized part of the memory you allocate. This means that you will continue to read character by character as long as this uninitialized data is not `(char) -1`, which will probably be well beyond the actual end of the file.

Instead try something like this:

```
char *data = NULL;
size_t c = 0;

for (;;)
{
    const int ch = fgets(fp);
    if (ch == EOF)
        break;  /* Error or end of file */

    char *tmp = realloc(data, c + 1);
    if (tmp == NULL)
        break;  /* Could not allocate memory */

    data = tmp;
    data[c++] = ch;
}
```

Comment: +1 with some minor edits; should point out that `realloc()` can fail, too.

Answer (score 1):

By the time your program tries to evaluate the following condition:

```
(data[c]!=EOF)
```

the `c` has already been incremented and `data[c]` thus tries to access the element out of range of the `data` array, resulting in ***undefined behavior***.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you will have to use a type cast with malloc coz malloc return a void*

```
data=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Also, EOF is not a char (EOF=-1)

The condition inside the while loop points to a yet uninitialized part of memory.

```
int ch;
while(1)
{
if( (ch=fgets(fp))==EOF )
    break;
data[c]=ch;
c++;
data=realloc(data, sizeof(char)+c);
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged C, so casting the return type of malloc is bad practice here. With C++ it's different.

Answer (score 0):

You have allocated ONE byte of memory. That is definiely not enough to read a file.

I suggest using `stat()` explained [How do you determine the size of a file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236/how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file-in-c) to get the size and then allocate `size*sizeof(char)`.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

off_t fsize(const char *filename) {
    struct stat st; 

    if (stat(filename, &st) == 0)
        return st.st_size;

    return -1; 
}

{
    FILE *fp;
    char *data;
    int c=0;
    off_t size = fsize("home/bob/Downloads/filename") +1;

    fp=fopen("home/bob/Downloads/filename", "r");
    data=malloc(sizeof(char) * size);

    do{
        data[c]=fgetc(fp);
        printf("data : %c\n", data[c]);
        c++;
        data=realloc(data, sizeof(char)+c);
    }while(data[c]!=EOF);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do{
    data[c]=fgetc(fp);
    printf("data : %c\n", data[c]);
    c++;
    data=realloc(data, sizeof(char)+c);
}while(data[c]!=EOF);  // this should be the location of the seg fault
```

While (data[c]) looks behind the end of the array.

Do

```
}while(data[c - 1]!=EOF);
```

Or increment c after the check

Answer (score 0):

```
data[c]=fgetc(fp);  --> This gives seg fault
```

Because you are incrementing like this `c++`

```
data=malloc(sizeof(char));
```

`data` points to a memory of `sizeof(char)` when you do `c++` then `data[c]` becomes UB.