# Handle memory while reading long lines from a file in C

Tags: c, string, file, memory-management

First of all, I know this question is very close to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277987/how-can-i-allocate-just-enough-memory-for-one-line-of-text-read-from-a-file-in-c), but the question was so poorly worded that I am not even sure it is a duplicate plus no code were shown so I thought it deserved to be asked properly.

I am trying to read a file line by line and I need to store a line in particular in a `variable`. I have managed to do so quite easily using `fgets`, nevertheless the **size of the lines to be read** and **the number of lines** in the file **remain unknown**.
I need a way to properly allocate memory to the `variable` whatever the size of the line might be, ***using C and not C++***.

So far my code looks like that :

```
allowedMemory = malloc(sizeof(char[1501])); // Checks if enough memory
if (NULL == allowedMemory)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory. \n");
    exit(1);
}
else
    char* res;
    res = allowedMemory;
while(fgets(res, 1500, file)) // Iterate until end of file
{
    if (res == theLineIWant) // Using strcmp instead of ==
        return res;
}
```

The problem of this code is that it is not adaptable at all. I am looking for a way to allocate just enough memory to `res` so that I don't miss any data in `line`.

I was thinking about something like that :

```
while ( lineContainingKChar != LineContainingK+1Char) // meaning that the line has not been fully read
// And using strcmp instead of ==
  realloc(lineContainingKChar, K + 100) // Adding memory
```

But I would need to iterate through two `FILE` object in order to fill these variables which would not be very efficient.
Any hints about how to implement this solution or advise about how to do it in a easier way would be appreciated.

EDIT : Seems like using `getline()` is the best way to do so because this function allocates the memory needed by itself and free it when needed. Nevertheless I don't think that it is 100% portable since I still can't use it though I have included `<stdio.h>`. To be verified though, since my issues are often situated between keyboard and computer. Until then I am still open to a solution which would not use POSIX-compliant C.

Comment: Have you tried [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html)?

Comment: `if (res == theLineIWant)` doesn't do what you think it does - to compare strings you need to use `strcmp`

Comment: If I am not wrong, getline() is either C++ either for Linux, so I can't use it ?
As for comparing string with `==`I know it does not work, but I thought it would be more readable like that. Will edit

Comment: @Badda *If I am not wrong, getline() is either C++ either for Linux*  `getline()` is POSIX-compliant C.  Note where that link points to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) appears to do exactly what you want:

> ***DESCRIPTION***
>
> The `getdelim()` function shall read from stream until it encounters a
>   character matching the delimiter character.
>
> ...
>
> The `getline()` function shall be equivalent to the `getdelim()`
>   function with the `delimiter` character equal to the `<newline>`
>   character.
>
> ...
>
> ***EXAMPLES***
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
>
>
> int main(void)
> {
>     FILE *fp;
>     char *line = NULL;
>     size_t len = 0;
>     ssize_t read;
>     fp = fopen("/etc/motd", "r");
>     if (fp == NULL)
>         exit(1);
>     while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
>         printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", read);
>         printf("%s", line);
>     }
>     if (ferror(fp)) {
>         /* handle error */
>     }
>     free(line);
>     fclose(fp);
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

And per [the Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html):

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> `getline()` reads an entire line from stream, storing the address of
>   the buffer containing the text into `*lineptr`.  The buffer is null-
>   terminated and includes the newline character, if one was found.
>
> If `*lineptr` is set to `NULL` and `*n` is set 0 before the call, then
>   `getline()` will allocate a buffer for storing the line.  This buffer
>   should be freed by the user program even if `getline()` failed.
>
> Alternatively, before calling `getline()`, `*lineptr` can contain a
>   pointer to a `malloc(3)`-allocated buffer `*n` bytes in size.  If the
>   buffer is not large enough to hold the line, `getline()` resizes it
>   with `realloc(3)`, updating `*lineptr` and `*n` as necessary.
>
> In either case, on a successful call, `*lineptr` and `*n` will be
>   updated to reflect the buffer address and allocated size respectively.

Comment: I am trying to make getline() work on my code, so far it is not recognized by compiler.

Comment: @Badda Are you including the proper headers?  And what compiler are you using?

Comment: I have included `stdlib`and `stdio`correctly. I am AtollicStudio IDE which uses GNU gcc ( I am not very familiar with these terms so I hope it is understable)

Comment: You need to add the proper feature test macros before including the headers in order to include for example POSIX features; "Since glibc 2.10: `_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L`".

Comment: @IljaEverilä More precisely: "**If you're using glibc**, [y]ou need to add the proper feature test macros..."  You probably should also add \@Badda (without the backslash - I had to add that so the comment system would allow that) to let Badda know.

Comment: I don't think it's just glibc specific. From ["2.2 The Compilation Environment"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02): "A POSIX-conforming application shall ensure that the feature test macro _POSIX_C_SOURCE is defined before inclusion of any header." Please correct if I've misread/misunderstood something.