# Printing off_t file size from dirent struct

Tags: c, printf, opendir

All i want is to print the size of a file in bytes
I am using

```
DIR *d;
struct dirent *dir;
d= opendir(absolute_path);

while((dir= readdir(d))!=NULL){
    printf("%s\t %d\t %u\n",dir->d_name,dir->d_type,(int long long )dir->d_off);
}
```

The printing of the d_off that is type `off_t` is wrong.
For a file of `323,388 bytes` it prints `1296623584`

I think that the casting is the problem. I tried lots of castings such as `%d` , `%s`,`%u`, `%llu`... 
What is the right casting?

EDIT: The right function to use to find filesize is `lstat()` using a stat struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andrey points out, the value of d_off is not always useful or even present. OSX does not have it for instance. Use a call to `stat` instead.

Comment: You have right `@sean-perry` ,`@andrey`. I used lstat() instead of stat!!! It worked well

Comment: Glad to hear it @KonKost. Note you should also check the file type in the dirent. Otherwise you will be calling `stat` on directories, FIFOs and who knows what else.

Answer (score 2):

From the `readdir` man page:

> Only the fields d_name and d_ino are specified  in  POSIX.1-2001.   The remaining  fields  are  available  on many, but not all systems.  Under glibc, programs can check  for  the  availability  of  the  fields  not defined in POSIX.1 by testing whether the macros _DIRENT_HAVE_D_NAMLEN, _DIRENT_HAVE_D_RECLEN, _DIRENT_HAVE_D_OFF, or  _DIRENT_HAVE_D_TYPE  are defined.
>
> The value returned in d_off is the same as would be returned by calling telldir(3) at the current position in the directory stream.   Be  aware that  despite  its type and name, the d_off field is seldom any kind of directory offset on modern filesystems.  Applications should treat this field as an opaque value, making no assumptions about its contents; see also telldir(3).

To find a file's size, see [How do you determine the size of a file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236/how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file-in-c)