# Helping optimize function to obtain the file size in a loop

Tags: c

I use this code to open in real time a recording file and use fseek() and ftell() to obtain the file size:

```
typedef struct _Recording Recording;
struct _Recording
{
    FILE *file;
    long filesize;
    int progress_id;
    ...
};

void start_recording(Recording *recording, char* filepath)
{
        ...         
        recording->file = fopen(filepath, "rb");
        recording->progress_id =
            g_timeout_add (500, (GSourceFunc) progress_timeout, recording);
}

gboolean progress_timeout (Recording *recording)
{
        if (recording->file != NULL)
        {
            fseek(recording->file, 0, SEEK_END);
            recording->filesize = ftell(recording->file);        
        }

        return TRUE;
}

void stop_recording(Recording *recording)
{
        ...
        if (recording->file)
        {
            fclose (recording->file);
            recording->file = NULL;
        }

       if (recording->progress_id != 0)
       {
            g_source_remove (recording->progress_id);
            recording->progress_id = 0;
       }
}
```

I use this function in a loop (500 ms). Need help to optimize function to be faster.

Efficiency of the code.

UPDATED with loop function

Comment: (not code-related, but..) What compiler do you use? Try `gcc -O3`.

Comment: Detail: use `long filesize;`

Comment: Better to use [fstat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat)

Comment: File IO is overall slow. Better check if storage hardware is saturated before optimizing. At the same time the performance measurement would differ between "cold start" and "hot start" because of buffering and cache.

Comment: If it is the loop you need optimising, it may be useful to include teh loop in the question - there may be other improvements possible in the unseen code.

Comment: Post *real* code.  Your function definition between file open/file close is not valid.  And what is the unused argument `filepath` for?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  Why do you need to check the file size so often?

Answer (score 3):

If you do not require "maximal" ([questioned](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/FIO19-C.+Do+not+use+fseek%28%29+and+ftell%28%29+to+compute+the+size+of+a+regular+file)) compatibility, it makes sense to [use operating system specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236/how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file-in-c) functions like `fstat`. Opening a file has always overhead and even seeking to the end - the operating system tries to anticipate what you're doing and may start caching file contents into memory - in this case needlessly.

Answer (score 2):

The code accesses the file-system; the performance of the file system and physical disk access will dominate.  Moreover most of the code that executes will be OS and file-system code, not yours, so no ammount of optimisation of your code is likely to help.

There may be some marginal benefit in using lower-level or OS specific APIs rather then stdio, such as [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html) or [`fstat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstat.html) for POSIX, or [`GetFileSizeEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364957(v=vs.85).aspx) in Windows for example.  These directly get the size rather than using `fseek()` so are likely to be faster, but perhaps not significantly for the reasons given.