# ftell/fseek is different from the actual readable data length in a /sys/class file

Tags: c, linux, file, sysfs

embedded linux system

1. `ls -al /sys/class/xxxx`
   `-r--r--r-- 4096`
2. ftell/lstat(st_size) return 4096
3. `fread(fp, 1, 4096, buf)` returns 3

Actually, there are only 3 bytes in file using vi to open it.

What's the problem?

Comment: If /sys is a sysfs partition, file are one page so 4k

Comment: I think 4096 byte is "size on disk" of the file, not is actual size of file

Comment: @Programmerdude Size on disk is reported by `du -sh`. Actual size is reported by `ls -l` and `du -sh --apparent-size`.

Answer (score 4):

`/sys` is a special filesystem where files are generated by the kernel on demand. See [`man sysfs(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysfs.5.html) for more details:

> The sysfs filesystem is a pseudo-filesystem which provides an interface to kernel data structures. (More precisely, the files and directories in sysfs provide a view of the kobject structures defined internally within the kernel.) The files under sysfs provide information about devices, kernel modules, filesystems, and other kernel components.

The size of files in `/sys` reported by `ls` is not the actual size because the contents of the files do not get generated just for the purpose of getting the file size. The contents are only generated upon `read` syscall.

Also note, that `fseek` and `ftell` won't report the actual file size for `sysfs` either because, again, the file content is only generated in `read` syscall.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the problem?

The problem is `fseek()`/`ftell()` is a fundamentally unsound way to get the size of a file.

Files can be opened in either binary or text mode.

For binary files, `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)` is explicitly undefined behavior.  Per [footnote 268 of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note268):

> Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)`, has undefined behavior for a binary stream (because of possible trailing null characters) or for any stream with state-dependent encoding that does not assuredly end in the initial shift state.

Per [**7.21.9.2 The fseek function**, paragraph 3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.2p3):

> ... A binary stream need not meaningfully support fseek calls with a whence value of SEEK_END.

So there's no portable, standards-compliant way to seek to the end of a binary stream.

And you can't use `ftell()` to get the size of a file opened in text mode.  Per [**7.21.9.4 The ftell function**, paragraph 2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.4p2)(note the bolded portions):

> The `ftell` function obtains the current value of the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by `stream`. For a binary stream, the value is the number of characters from the beginning of the file. **For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information**, usable by the fseek function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the ftell call; **the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read.**

You can't seek to the end of a binary stream, and you can't use `ftell` to get the size of a text stream.

Comment: A downvote without a comment, when the code posted in the question is **explicitly** undefined behavior because it uses `fseek(.., SEEK_END)` on a binary stream?  And gets unexpected results?

Comment: Very well explained. Tks!

Comment: But this method does de-facto work on normal files on most systems, so IDK if it explains the behaviour seen in this question.  Unix system calls like `lseek` may have the same problem on sysfs files, in which case it's not really due to the C stdio layer's refusal to define enough behaviour to be useful.  It's interesting, but IDK if it's the right place for it.  Surely there's a Q&A about portably finding file lengths in C where this answer would fit, warning against what I thought was the standard way?  (A link to such an answer would make a good comment on this question).

Comment: Yeah, just tried it with `strace` on a program that makes an `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)`, and that syscall returns 4096 on `strace ./lseek /sys/class/tty/console/active`, vs. `wc` on the same file only reading 5 bytes.  https://godbolt.org/z/Mcderd7Gx for the source of my lseek wrapper.  So even the well-defined POSIX system calls don't work; it's not really due to C allowing an implementation to leave this behaviour undefined.

Answer (score -1):

In unix system block size of the file system must be 4 kB. 
I dont want duplicate answer so check this:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62049/why-are-text-files-4kb 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system#Space_management

If you want have real byte size of file use this:

```
fp = fopen("...", "rb");
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
size_t size = ftell(fp);
```

And if you want read from file reset seek to begin:

```
rewind(fp);
```

OR

```
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: `fp = fopen("...", "r");` opens the file in text mode. You can't use `ftell()` to get the size of a file in text mode. Per [**7.21.9.4 The ftell function**, paragraph 2 of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.4):  "For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the fseek function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the ftell call; **the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read.**"

Comment: @AndrewHenle You right, i dont say this is count of **characters**, this is **byte size**. But true is open file like a text can be confusing, i`ll cange.

Comment: `ls -l` displays actual size in bytes, not used size.  On most filesystems, the reported size matches the actual readable length for regular files, it's sysfs that's weird.  (It doesn't know the exact length because the contents are only generated on the fly when you actually read.  It would be a waste of CPU time to actually do that just to get the length for `stat` system calls.)