# C/ String data from file to array. Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, arrays, stream

I am writing a program that streams words from a text file and puts them into an array. I've also added a display of array data to see if everything is ok but I get a segmentation fault after compiling.

I am new to system programming so I am aware I might have done some basic mistakes. Please find the code below and tell me where have I gone wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFER 100

int main() {
    char tab[BUFFER];
    FILE *wp;
    wp = fopen("tab_file_b_words.txt", "r");
    if(wp == NULL)
    {
        printf("error/n");
        return -1;
    }
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<sizeof(wp); i++) {
        if(wp != NULL)
            fscanf(wp, "%s", &tab[i]);
        else 
            break;
        }
    printf("Content: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < BUFFER; i++) {
        if(tab[i] != NULL)
            printf("%s\n", tab[i]);
        else 
            break;
        }
    fclose(wp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you trace the program's executing using a debugger, at what point does the program first behave differently than you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section:

```
for(i=0; i<sizeof(wp); i++) {
    if(wp != NULL)
        fscanf(wp, "%s", &tab[i]);
    else 
        break;
    }
```

Is problematic.

First, there are a couple of issues with the line: `fscanf(wp, "%s", &tab[i]);`  It should be written as:
`fscanf(wp, "%s", tab); //removed & and array notation.`
Unlike `int` or `float` variable types, the name of your `char` array (i.e. `tab`) is already a pointer pointing to the address of the variable, making it unnecessary (and incorrect) to use the *address of*  operator (`&`).

Related to above... *(and likely cause of segmentation fault.)*
Because the definition of `tab` is for a simple array of `char` ( `char tab[BUFFER];` ), the notation `tab[i]` refers only to the ith `byte` (or `char`) of the array, not the entire array.  Because of the `"%s"` format specifier used, the function *[fscanf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm)* expects a `char *` not a `char`, making `tab` the correct argument to use.

If you want to use an array of lines the variable must be created as a *2D* array of char:

```
#define NUM_LINES 100
#define LINE_LEN 80

int main() {
    char tab[NUM_LINES][LINE_LEN] = {{0}}; // zero initialized array of 
                                           // NUM_LINE strings
                                           // each of LINE_LEN-1 capacity
```

In the statement `for(i=0; i<sizeof(wp); i++) {`

`sizeof(wp)`

will be equal to the number of bytes of the pointer `wp`,  either 32 or 64 depending on the target addressing of your application.  This is probably not what you intended. (or want.)

*Consider a different approach:*
Given you are working with text files, try using a combination of `while()` and *[fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)* to read lines from the file.  Then you can process each line based on its known syntax.
(Following example uses a single dimension `char` array for simplified illustration.)

```
char line[some_len];

wp = fopen(some_file_name, "r");
if(wp)
{
    while(fgets(line, some_len, wp))
    {
        // use line.  In this case, just print to stdout
        printf("%s\n", line);
    }
    fclose(wp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. As of now you are having array of `char`

   what you need is

   ```
      char tab[BUFFER]; --> char tab[BUFFER][SOME_LENGTH];
   ```

   And

   ```
      fscanf(wp, "%s", &tab[i]); --> fscanf(wp, "%s", tab[i]);
   ```
2. `%s` expects `null` terminated `char *` but you are passing `char`.

   ```
       printf("%s\n", tab[i]);
   ```
3. `sizeof(wp)` is size of pointer.

   ```
   for(i=0; i<sizeof(wp); i++)
   ```

   What you need is

   ```
     while (1 == fscanf(wp, "%s", tab[i]))
     {
            ...
     }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(wp)` is the problem.
`sizeof` returns the length of a type in bytes and not the length of the file.

If you want to get the size of a file [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236/how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file-in-c) may help you.