# How to read() from a file continuosly into a variable

Tags: c, unix

I am trying to perform a read() from a file of which I don't know it's exact size into a variable so that I can do stuff on it later on, so I am looping like this:

```
char buf[BUFSIZE];
char* contentsOfFile;

fd = open(file, O_RDONLY);

while ( (nbytes = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)) ) > 0) { // keep reading until the end of file or error 
    strcat(contentsOfFile, buf);
}
```

Of course, this explodes unless contentsOfFile is another char array, but I cannot do this as
I could have a bigger file than the number of bytes it could hold.

Is there any other library solution, or should I resort to `malloc`?

Comment: `strcat()` stops when (if) it finds a `0` and you then overwrite the rest of the buffer in the next loop. Or you overflow the destination when `strcat()` does not find a `0`.

Comment: And `char* contentsOfFile;` has no memory allocated.

Comment: Why not find the size of the file and read it all at once into an appropriately sized buffer? Or just `mmap()` it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `malloc`. Find the size first ([How do you determine the size of a file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236/how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file-in-c)) then malloc the appropriate number of bytes and do the `read`.

Comment: or if the file very large map it into the address space. (nmap or CreateFileA in windows)

Comment: @eewanco Thanks! I hadn't remembered to use `stat`, that's a handy solution. I'm still learning C and system calls so I will check `mmap`  in the (near) future

Answer (score 1):

This is terrible code:

- `contentsOfFile` is an unitialized pointer, so dereferencing it invokes UB
- `read` returns raw bytes and never adds any terminating null (unformatted io), but `strcat` expects null terminated strings.

Without more context, it is hard to tell you what is the correct way. Possible ways are:

- use `mmap` to map the file content into memory. After that, you can process it transparently and the OS will load and unload *pages* from the file when required
- load everything into memory using `malloc` and `realloc` to make sure to have enough allocated memory for next read
- load everything into memory using one single `malloc` and one single read after finding the file size.