# Words breaking into stange symbols in decrypted text when performing authenticated encryption/decrpytion using OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl, hmacsha256

I am working on using OpenSSL in Linux Ubuntu to perform authenticated encryption/decryption. I am currently using C for the code, AES-CTR Encryption method for ciphering the text, HMAC-SHA256 for the tag. My code works by using Makefile for command "make"; after that, using the two instructions shown below and original.txt for original text, shared.key for the key to encrypt/decrypt. **My problem** here is that although **no error occurs**(I tried to handle as many errors as possible, but there can be more...) during encryption and decryption, when I open the decryption.txt file, generated after the decrpytion, the **words are broken into stange symbols**...

Here is the **C code** that I've written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>

char* readFile(char* fileName){
    int size;
    int count;
    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);
    char* buffer = malloc(size+1);
    char* result = malloc(size+1);
    memset(buffer, 0, size+1);
    memset(result, 0, size+1);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while(1){
        char* pStr = fgets(buffer, size+1, fp);
        if(pStr==NULL)break;
        strcat(result, pStr);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    free(buffer);
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    if(argc != 10){
        printf("ERROR\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    int ikey, iin, iout, itag;
    for(int i=2; i < 9;i+=2){
        if(!strcmp(argv[i], "-key")) ikey = i+1;
        else if(!strcmp(argv[i], "-in")) iin = i+1;
        else if(!strcmp(argv[i], "-out")) iout = i+1;
        else if(!strcmp(argv[i], "-tag")) itag = i+1;
    }
    if(ikey+iin+iout+itag != 24){
        printf("ERROR\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    char* key = readFile(argv[ikey]);
    char *iv = "0123456789012345";



    if(!strcmp(argv[1], "enc")){
        FILE *inFp = fopen(argv[iin],"rb");
        FILE *outFp = fopen(argv[iout], "wb");
        int inLen, outLen;
        char inBuf[BUFSIZ], outBuf[BUFSIZ+EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
        EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_ctr(), NULL, key, iv);
        while((inLen=fread(inBuf, 1, sizeof(inBuf), inFp))>0){

            if(!EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, outBuf, &outLen, inBuf, inLen)){
                printf("ERROR\n");
                EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
                exit(2);
            }
            fwrite(outBuf, 1, outLen, outFp);
        }
        if(!EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, outBuf, &outLen)){
            printf("ERROR\n");
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
            exit(2);
        }
        fwrite(outBuf, 1, outLen, outFp);
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);

        fclose(inFp);
        fclose(outFp);
        char* cipher = readFile(argv[iout]);
        char* hashVal;
        hashVal = HMAC(EVP_sha256(), key,strlen((char*)key), cipher, strlen((char*)cipher), NULL, NULL);
        FILE *tagFp = fopen(argv[itag], "w");
        fwrite(hashVal, 1, strlen(hashVal), tagFp);
        exit(0);
    }
    else if(!strcmp(argv[1], "dec")){
        FILE *inFp = fopen(argv[iin],"rb");
        char* cipher = readFile(argv[iin]);
        char* hashVal;
        hashVal = HMAC(EVP_sha256(), key,strlen(key), cipher, strlen(cipher), NULL, NULL);
        char* compareVal = readFile(argv[itag]);
        if(strcmp(compareVal, hashVal) != 0){
            printf("VERIFICATION FAILURE\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        FILE *outFp = fopen(argv[iout], "wb");
        int inLen, outLen;
        char inBuf[BUFSIZ], outBuf[BUFSIZ+EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
        EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_ctr(), NULL, key, iv);
        //printf("First Buf %s\n", outBuf);
        //printf("First Buf %s\n", inBuf);
        while((inLen=fread(inBuf, 1, sizeof(inBuf), inFp))>0){
            //printf("Second Buf %s\n", outBuf);
            //printf("Second Buf %s\n", inBuf);
            if(!EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, outBuf, &outLen, inBuf, inLen)){
                printf("ERROR\n");
                EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
                exit(2);
            }
            //printf("Third Buf %s\n", outBuf);
            //printf("Third Buf %s\n", inBuf);
            //printf("First number %d\n", inLen);
            fwrite(outBuf, 1, outLen, outFp);
        }
        if(!EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, outBuf, &outLen)){
            printf("ERROR\n");
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
            exit(2);
        }
        fwrite(outBuf, 1, outLen, outFp);
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
        fclose(inFp);
        fclose(outFp);
        exit(0);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

And below is the **Makefile** that I have used to compile the upper code with gcc, using "make" command:

```
cryp: cryp.o
    gcc -o $@ cryp.o -lssl -lcrypto

cryp.o: cryp.c
```

For the original.txt and shared.key, I just typed a simple sentence like "This is original text" and "This is shared key".
With these elements, I used `./cryp enc -key shared.key -in original.txt -out encrypted.txt -tag encrypted.tag` instruction in Linux terminal(Within the file storage that contains the elements) for encryption, and `./cryp dec -key shared.key -in encrypted.txt -tag encrypted.tag -out decrypted.txt` instuction for decryption.
After these actions, I expected a decrypted.txt that contains same content as original.txt, but the generated decrypted.txt showed **words that are broken into stange symbols**...What can I do to fix this situation? PLEASE help...

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your code works for me. Pay attention to type/signedness issues ... `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wpointer-sign ...`

Comment: @pmg Thanks for the comment! It is a relief that as it works for your environment, code is not wrong, but now the question is, why does it not working on my environment...Can I ask whay do you mean by type/signedness issues and the following command?

Comment: @pmg With your comment, I looked into the readFile function code, and fixed it, and it worked!! I don't know if this modification is what you actually mean with type/signedness issues, but THANKS anyway!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the kind comments and answers, I examined the code, and fixed the readFile() function part, and it worked! I am posting this to save others who may suffer from same problem...
The changed **readFile() function** looks like this:

```
char* readFile(const char* filename) {
    FILE* fp;
    char* buffer = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    size_t read_size;

    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return NULL;
    }

    while (!feof(fp)) {
        buffer = realloc(buffer, size + 1024);  // increase buffer size by 1024 bytes
        if (buffer == NULL) {
            perror("Error allocating memory");
            fclose(fp);
            return NULL;
        }
        read_size = fread(buffer + size, 1, 1024, fp);  // read 1024 bytes from file
        size += read_size;
    }

    buffer = realloc(buffer, size + 1);  // increase buffer size by 1 byte for null terminator
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        perror("Error allocating memory");
        fclose(fp);
        return NULL;
    }
    buffer[size] = '\0';  // add null terminator to end of buffer

    fclose(fp);
    return buffer;
}
```

Thanks for the help, **AGAIN**!

Answer (score 0):

One problem that could be causing your issue if you're running on Windows is this code

```
FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(fp);
```

does not tell you the size of the file.  (Nevermind even if it does "work" it will still fail anyway for files larger than 2 GB...)

`fp` is a text stream, and per [**7.21.9.4 The ftell function**, paragraph 2 of the (draft) C11 standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.4p2) (bolding mine):

> For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the `fseek` function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the `ftell` call; **the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read.**

Whoever taught you to use `fseek()`/`ftell()` to get the size of a file taught you a fundamentally flawed method.  It's not portable - it won't work on text streams on Windows, for just one example.

And [you can't fix that by using a binary stream, either](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.2p3):

> A binary stream need not meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a whence value of `SEEK_END`.

[In fact](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#note268):

> Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)`, has undefined behavior for a binary stream...

See [**How do you determine the size of a file in C?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236/how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file-in-c).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Although I am running this code on Ubuntu environment, this can be the problem...