Using OpenSSL's SHA1 with Apple Silicon in C
I am building a git clone and working on the hash-file command. I am currently trying to compute the SHA1 hash of a known string and have this code and the following issue:
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int hashFile(char *file_name, int ww) {
    int i, ret;
    size_t size_len;
    unsigned long file_size;
    char path[56];
    unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    char *token, *type, *blob_content, *content;

    FILE *src = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (ferror(src)) {
        perror("Unable to read file");
        return 1;
    }
    fseek(src, 0L, SEEK_END);
    file_size = ftell(src);
    rewind(src);
    size_len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%lu", file_size);

    char *buffer = (char *)malloc((size_t)file_size + 1);
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), file_size, src);
    buffer[file_size] = '\0';

    blob_content = (char *)malloc((7 + sizeof(unsigned long) + file_size + 1) *
                                  sizeof(char));
    snprintf(blob_content, 7 + size_len + 1, "blob %lu\\0", file_size);
    strcat(blob_content, buffer);

    SHA1((unsigned char *)blob_content, strlen(blob_content), hash);
    printf("%s\n", hash);

    free(blob_content);
    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}

void printHashHelp() {
    printf("usage: twat hash-file [options] <file_name>\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("options:\n");
    printf("\t-w: write contents to objects store\n");
}

$ clang --std=c17 -fmodules -fprebuilt-module-path=. -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include cmd.c comp.c init.c cat.c hash.c -o twat -v
...
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_SHA1", referenced from:
      _hashFile in hash-fc3ff3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

How should I go about linking and enabling SHA1 to work on the M2 Max? What clang command should I be using if this is incorrect?
I have been trying different methods of linking openssl/sha.h and believed to have got it but have not got the function to work currently.
Following: How to use SHA1 hashing in C programming I attempted to use the linked library but got a compiler linking failure.

First, FILE *src = fopen(file_name, "r"); if (ferror(src))??  Why are you using ferror() to check if fopen() succeeded?  fopen() returns NULL on failure, and ferror(NULL) invokes undefined behavior. Second, you're opening the file in text mode, which means ftell() does not give you a byte count.  In fact, using fseek()/ftell() to get a file's size is fundamentally broken.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236/how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file-in-c.  You need to hash the file contents no matter what they are.  And how are you going to hash a 382 GB file?

note - if your file has any binary data, your reliance on strcat and snprintf to do the right thing will create unpredictable results.

@AndrewHenle Thanks for pointing this out - getting the file size that way was a little stupid - I got the ferror thing from the zlib manpage so I was just going with that.

@selbie I am thinking this is only going to be used on text data - what would you recommend to generalise it?

@h5law - I updated my answer with some more hints for improvement after you accepted.  Hope this helps.

@h5law - if you use "rb" on windows with fopen, it will aid in compatibility since \r\n won't get translated differently.  See my updated answer below.

Append
-L/opt/homebrew/lib -lcrypto

to your command line.
Also, your malloc and snprintf looks weird. The whole +1 and +7 looks error prone
This would be better:
char header[100] = {0};  // 100 is big enough for the entire "blob 12345" thing regardless of how big the file is

SHA1_CTX ctx = {0};
SHA1_Init(&ctx);
sprintf(header, "blob %lu", file_size);
SHA1_Update(&ctx, header, strlen(header));
SHA1_Update(&ctx, buffer, file_size);
SHA1_Final(hash, &ctx);

And then if you really want to be pedantic, make sure you open the file as binary on non-Unix:
#ifdef _WIN32
    char* flags = "rb";
#else
    char* flags = "r";
#endif

FILE *src = fopen(file_name, flags);


make sure you open the file as binary on non-Unix  I'd think it'd be easier to just open it in binary with "rb" on all platforms.

Since openssl@3.x the Init Update and Final commands have been deprecated according to their docs in favour of the SHA1 command. The strange malloc is because the blob_content needs to hold the entire file - I think writing to disk may be a better option compared to keeping the string in memory but instead a temporary file.

@AndrewHenle - I didn't have a chance to look this up, but I thought some platforms didn't recognize "b" as a flag to fopen, even if it was a no-op.  This might no longer be the case.

@selbie Possible, although such would probably be out-of-date by now.  C99 seems to have required support for the b flag.  And there's no telling how it would work in general on z/OS...
